# Need a hitTestPoint solution to replace hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I need an as3 solution to this collision problem:

I have this code:

```
else if (objectArray[i].toString().indexOf("meandude") != -1) {
            //if the object is a meandude and hits it, game over
            if (projectileMC.hitTestObject(objectArray[i])) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mainEnterFrame);loseGame();
```

which is using the bounding boxes of the projectileMC and meandude (hitTestObject). I'd  like it so the center points of the projectileMC and meandude crossing registers the action instead (hitTestPoint). I tried to switch it myself, but I'm not getting it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what your precise problem is without seeing more of your code. But as a first guess I would think you want to solve the following problem:

Your hittest is not being triggered when your projectile hits the "meandude" when you use the hitTestObject.

And

You try to solve the problem by using the hitTestPoint instead?

The test might not trigger simple because your projectile is moving too fast. If the distance between XY_ThisFram before colisison and then XY_NextFrame is bigger than the size of of your "meandude" it won't ever collide. I suggest you don't use hitTestObject to do any collision in your game as it is not reliable, especially for fast moving display objects.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. Let me try again. There is one movieclip (projectileMC) that, if it hits a different movieclip (meandude), ends the game. The code above works fine, but because the meandude is an organic shape, and not a rectangle, the projectile never "looks" like it hits the organic shape... it's the two bounding boxes that are hitting. I'd like the center of the projectile to have to cross the center of the meandude in order for the game to end. I think that would be hitTestPoint? But, I don't know how to code that in my code above.

Comment: Yes that would be the normal behaviour of any MC, Sprite or Shape in Flash. You would have to create your own collision frame using fixed line boundaries. If your object can be surrounded by a convex shape it is quite easy. See http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/ on how this could be implemented in general. This would also require you don't use hitTestPoint/Object as they always work against the unrotated bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

Flash doesn't have a good object-to-object hit test for the general case.  If both projectileMC and meandude are bitmaps, you can try [BitmapData.hitTest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29).